# Can I tell in JavaScript whether the visitor's locale follows the U.S style or the rest of the world's style?

Tags: javascript, date, localization

Is there an unobtrusive way to tell in JavaScript whether a visitor's locale uses the U.S. month-day-year convention or the rest of the world's day-month-year convention? Will a new Date().toLocaleDateString() put the month in the right place for how things should be done on the computer's locale?

Answer (score 1):

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

userLanguage for IE and language for everything else. en-US will be English US.